# Connecting one MQ server to multiple weblogic instances possible/not-possible?

Tags: ibm-mq, weblogic11g

Hi I have a IBM MQ server 7.0.1 installed on one centralized machine. The requirement is to connect many weblogic instances to this. The weblogic version is 12.1.3.

Is this possible or not. If yes how can do this configuration and in which file. I can specify only one PROVIDER_URL in JMSAdmin.config file.

Answer (score 1):

First, MQ 7.0.1 is now very old and not supported by IBM. If you're making a new deployment I recommend deploying on one of the later still supported release (7.1, 7.5, 8, or 9).

MQ queue managers are capable of handling many thousands of clients, so this isn't a problem. The JMSAdmin configuration is deployed to each of the Weblogic servers, and it describes how to connect to the queue manager. You might decide to deploy the same JMSAdmin config to all of the Weblogic servers, as they could all connect to the same queue manager via the same channel.

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

> I have a IBM MQ server 7.0.1 installed on one centralized machine.

That version of MQ is no longer supported by IBM.  Upgrade to a supported version of MQ.

> The requirement is to connect many weblogic instances to this.

Not a problem.

> The weblogic version is 12.1.3.

Follow the instructions in the Weblogic manual.

Comment: @Tim McCormick : Actually I have been asked to install this 7.0.1 version of MQ and customers are on the same version of MQ server. Yes that worked for me. Now I have assigned one queue manager to each weblogic and configuring it as : JMSAdmin.bat<mq.scp. Further more there were some issues related to security while trying to acces the remote machine. In order to solve this the users must be added to the mqm group in the Group/User manager panel and this starts working.   Thanks Tim and Everyone.

Comment: @Ankit_ceo2 Just for completeness, all MQ clients can interoperate with all queue manager versions. Just because the queue manager (server) is at 7.0.1, doesn't mean you have to use a 7.0.1 client. You could just as easily use 7.1, 7.5, 8, or 9.